# Unable to import a swift package into my Objective C class that is specified under public headers in SPM

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager

I have a package that is a complete Objective C framework, this contains an include folder with my bridging-header. Now which ever class is exposed using this bridging header to my Swift project, i can't import any module into it. I get module not found error.

Project structure

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand the question how it's currently written. The title says you want to add Swift package to Objective-C class, while in description you ask how to use Objective-C framework in your Swift project. Could you provide your project structure and better explain which part you want to include in which part of it

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Thanks for reaching out, so my issue is that, i have added a local package via SPM in my project, this particular package is completely written in Objective C. Now when i expose a class from this package to my main app which is written in Swift, I have specified this Objective C class in my bridging header. When i import another package into the same class it gives me an error saying Module is not found.

Comment: `When i import another package into the same class` i'm not quite following what it means. The Obj-C headers imported in the bridging header (and the classes exposed there) are supposed to be available project-wide if you deal with Swift classes. Could you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which include your bridging header and (ideally) project structure?

Comment: If you see the project structure i have attached to my original comment, so the class that i have imported in my bridging header, when i import Package beta into it thats when i get an error.

Comment: I can't see any Objective-C classes there. If you want to use a Swift framework inside of a Swift classes, you link the framework and import it whenever it's needed with `import FrameworkName`